Can't think of movie name from trailer I saw
I saw a movie trailer on iTunes nearly 2 years ago and all I can vaguely remember is that it showed a guy falling through a roof (or maybe a window?) and he landed in someone's city apartment pretty beat-up. Then at some point the man opened a fridge. Then the lights turned on. And I think at some point the man was going down a fire escape? The entire scene took place at night. The trailer seemed pretty mysterious, it didn't really give away much of the movie. As for the genre I believe it was an action or thriller.
Does this movie trailer seem familiar to anyone? Sorry this is all I can remember, I wish I could remember more details. I've tried searching everywhere for it and talked to multiple people with no luck. It must have been a pretty popular movie though considering I only came across it because it was top on iTunes.
Additional Info: The trailer does not cut to many different scenes. It simply shows the scene I described above and ends. There are also not many characters shown in the trailer. I believe it was only 1 or 2 characters. The man breaks into city apartment, goes and opens the fridge, lights turn on and I think another man appears.
Also a friend I was with recalls that the description had something to do with drugs. I have no idea if this is true, I figure I post it just in case it helps jog someone's memory.
More Info:
Just to give some more information. This is how my friend and I remember the movie. The trailer starts off by showing this guy fall/break through a roof. He lands in someone's city apartment at night and it is implied that there is a man chasing him based on the movement of the main character. The main character then at one point opens a fridge (not really sure why or what he grabs). And the lights turn on (I'm guessing the people in the apartment turned the lights on when they heard someone, OR maybe the apartment was empty and the main character turned the lights on to make it look like people in the apartment woke-up). So the man who is chasing the main character then goes down the fire escape after realizing that people might be awake in that apartment and the trailer ends. This is all the trailer showed. It didn't cut to many different scenes, it was simply a trailer that showed this particular scene from the movie and then ended. It was pretty mysterious which is why I am really interested in the movie.

Do you remember the actor or actress you saw in the trailer?

@EdmDroid Unfortunately I do not. There were only 1-2 characters in the trailer shown.

What I have started doing is looking at all movies trailers released over the past few years. So far no luck but hopefully one day I will find it. I wonder if there is a way I can find a picture similar to a scene that I recall from the trailer (such as the scene with the man opening the fridge) and do a reverse image search on movies that way?

Maybe we can find the movie by searching the history of Top iTunes movies? Do you perhaps remember approximate date of you seeing the movie and that movie being in the top?

Sounds a lot like a scene from Redemption, starring Jason Stratham. He's homeless, he's being chased... he escapes into this rich guy's apartment, via, I believe it's the skylight. Turns out the rich guy is out of town for several months and Jason Stratham takes over the guy's apartment and his identity and uses the opportunity to redeem himself on many levels. I've seen it a couple of times. I enjoyed it. 

From the description, the first thought I had was the trailer for Watchmen. There are iconic scenes in the movie that describe quite a bit of one of the main characters, The Comedian, Rorschach, and others.
Falling through window - The comedian

Running away from the cops - Rorschach

Here is the full cinematic trailer that will hopefully jog your memory. Hope this is it!
Watchmen Cinematic Trailer

I really appreciate the effort, but unfortunately this is not the movie. The trailer that I am thinking of doesn't cut to many different scenes. The trailer simply shows the scene I described above and ends. I also know that the movie is not a super-hero type movie.
